# Dynamically add to array in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, input

I am trying to take input from a form, add it to an array, and `print_r` that array to the screen.

My problem is that the input from the form only replaces the first (and only) element in the array.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="sub"/>
</form>

<?php
    $a = array();

    if( isset($_REQUEST['text']) && !empty($_REQUEST['text'])){
        array_push($a, $_REQUEST['text']);
        print_r($a);
    }
?>
```

One theory of mine is that `$a` keeps getting re-assigned on the first line of PHP code (`$a = array();`), but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have looked around, but can't find an answer.

Comment: Are you wanting to accumulate values between various posts?  In that case, you're going to have to either send the array contents back and forth on the page (perhaps as a hidden input element) between posts, or persist the array contents in a database.  Each post causes the server to start with a comletely "empty" instance of php, it knows nothing of what the array previously was.

Comment: Are you only trying to get this to update on the screen?  Do you plan on submitting this later?  It sounds as if you should be doing this all on the client side (i.e. JavaScript)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The array *does* get reinitialized each time the form is posted. What you'll want to do is have your array as a more persistent data source.

1. You might consider using a session and the [`$_SESSION` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

```
session_start();
if (!is_array($_SESSION['a'])){
  $_SESSION['a'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['a'][] = $_REQUEST['text'];
```

1. You might also consider [writing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) this data to a small text file that you could then [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) at the start of the script.
2. Another option would be to [write the data to a `$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: I decided to write the data to a text file, it seems to be working well. I just need to figure out how to add a new line, probably "\n" or "<br/>". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing client and server execution...
If you want an array of text you should use something like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="text[]" />
    <input type="text" name="text[]" />
    <input type="text" name="text[]" />

    <input type="submit" name="sub"/>
</form>
```

If you want more entry of text being added you should inject more input with javascript

Comment: I don't know how to handle forms in javascript... I was hoping for having one text box, and each time you press "submit" the value of the text box get's appended to the array, and re-echo's onto the screen. Is there an easier way to do this in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You are not replacing anything, what you're doing is adding the value of `$_REQUEST['text']` to the array, which was empty before.